# Does overriding toString() cause different behavior than overriding normal methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I came across an inheritance problem on javadeathmatch.com that I cannot seem to wrap my head around. My understanding of polymorphism is that the objects will behave as they are instantiated (ie Object a = new Child()) will behave as a child since it is a child object in memory. Thus, shouldn't p2 first search for it's own toString() method before calling it's parents in the code below?

After a bit of exploring I discovered that p2.name sets Person's instance variable, which I find quite contrary to what I've learned about methods and inheritance. Are there different rules for fields?

```
public class Person {
    public String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {  return name;    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    public String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {  return name;    }
}

      Person p1 = new Person();
      Person p2 = new Student();

      p1.name = "ricky";
      p2.name = "maru";

      System.out.println(p1.toString() + p2);

}

Output is rickynull
I would have guessed rickymaru
```

Comment: Fields aren't methods. p2 is declared as **Person**, so when you go p2.name, the compilers assumes that you want the Person.name field, not the Student.name field. Because, as the DUP question explains: there is no polymorphism for fields, only for methods. Therefore the *only* reasonable way to use fields in inheritance is when they are *protected* and *meant* to be used by subclasses!

Comment: @Ghostcat thank you that helps clarify things a lot

Comment: @GhostCat I'd even advocate for the purist approach of not using `protected` fields either. I think that `private` should be the only modifier used for fields. (I'd even propose to have a modifier that is *stronger than private*, but that may be controversial).

Comment: @Marco13 I think the "controverse" starts with the fact: what keyword would you use for a "stronger than private" modifier? ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat It's just a thought, we won't sort this out here (and they won't change the language, for that matter ;-)), but I thought of fields that are "local" for setters+getters (in the sense of: only accessible for setters+getters), and thus, `local` could be one...

Answer (score 0):

It's the variable that causes the different behaviour. When you make a variable of the same name in a subclass, that's called hiding. The resulting subclass will now actually have both properties. You can access the one from the superclass with super.var or ((SuperClass)this).var. The variables don't even have to be of the same type; they are just two variables sharing a name, much like two overloaded methods.